# Feedburner doesn't update when "scheduled post" publishes

Tags: feedburner, scheduled-posts

I've searched around and can't find anything on this, so thought I'd see if y'all could help. I am successfully scheduling posts and having them publish - no "missed schedule" problems - but when a scheduled post is published, WordPress does not ping Feedburner, and my feed is not updated. I can manually go into Feedburner and update the feed, but that's a pain (well, it's easy, but I forget to do it! that's the whole point of scheduling posts! :-) ).

Does anyone know of a setting in either Feedburner or WordPress that I need to change to make this work? My 'privacy' settings are set to visible to search engines. Here's the site if that helps in any way: http://thegladdestthing.com/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is FeedBurner pinged? By a plugin? If so: Which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird, but you can try this. Go to **WordPress Dashboard > Settings > Writing** administration screen, and to the existing URIs listed under **Update Services**, add this:

```
http://ping.feedburner.com
```

**More Info:** [WordPress Codex — XML-RPC Ping Services](http://codex.wordpress.org/Update_Services#XML-RPC_Ping_Services)

Comment: Thank you! Either that did it or something changed in Feedburner or WordPress in the year since I asked the question but it's working now that I've made that change. Yay! Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Michelle Glad it worked, and looks like I've learnt something too! :)